# s3cmd - request signature calculated does not match signature provided?

Tags: amazon-s3

I've been stuck on this for a while and can't seem to figure out what is wrong.
I'm trying to [use s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) to push recursively a local directory (on my mac) to my S3 account.  I was following along [this guide](http://www.maxmasnick.com/2012/01/21/jekyll_s3_cloudfront/) and am having trouble when I get to the `sync` command.

I tried running this first to setup the credentials on s3cmd

```
s3cmd --configure

#It asks for the following...
#supply my access key
#supply my secret key
#set Default region
#encryption password - leave blank default
#GPG - leave blank default
#use https - leave default no
#Http proxy server - leave blank default
```

I'm then prompted and run `Test access with supplied credentials?`
Which shows the following, leaving me to believe it can connect fine.

```
Please wait, attempting to list all buckets...
Success. Your access key and secret key worked fine :-)

Now verifying that encryption works...
Not configured. Never mind.
```

I then try to run the s3cmd command to put my files in the bucket, but get an error.

```
s3cmd put -r myLocalDir/ s3://mybucket  
WARNING: Module python-magic is not available. Guessing MIME types based on file extensions.
asking for bucket location
WARNING: Forwarding request to us-west-2
myLocalDir/.DS_Store -> s3://mybucket/.DS_Store  [1 of 96]
 6148 of 6148   100% in    0s    63.50 kB/s  done
ERROR: S3 error: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

Any ideas what I'm setting wrong or how I can check what it's trying to authenticate against?  I'm able to run the read commands fine (ie. `s3cmd ls`), but can't seem to push anything

Comment: Please note your s3cmd version, and run with --debug.  I have several reports of failures with signature-v4 signing but I have not been able to reproduce them to debug the failure.

Comment: @MattDomsch I actually ended up just using the aws-cli instead , but sure I'll update this when I get home tonight.